# Android: View in lower resolution screen (ldpi) truncated

Tags: android, fragment, dpi

I'm implementing my view and have been testing with xdpi hdpi and tvdpi mdpi, and they all look fine.
However, a quick test in a ldpi device, it seems like parts of my views are being truncated. Why is that? My contents are truncated both horizontally (right part truncated), and vertically (the content seems to go off the bottom of the screen without any scroll bar available for me to scroll).

My View uses fragments via the support library. The fragment which has its bottom truncated is as follow:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/event_title"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#20b2aa"/>

<EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/event_title"
        android:id="@+id/new_event_title"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:shadowColor="#20b2aa"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_custom"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/suggested_times"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="#20b2aa"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/date_selection"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/suggestion"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="66dp"
            android:id="@+id/add_suggested_time_btn"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/social_person"
           android:src="@drawable/social_person"
            android:contentDescription="Suggest a time"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/invitees"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="#20b2aa"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/invitee_selection"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">


    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:id="@+id/add_invitee_btn"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
            android:background="@drawable/social_add_person"
            android:contentDescription="Suggest a time"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<!-------------- CONTENT FROM HERE ON ARE OFF THE SCREEN ------------------------>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/description"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="#20b2aa"/>

<EditText
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_custom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/description"
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        />
```

The above fragment is added into this following container inside `fragment_container`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_image">

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you provide images for ldpi devices in res folder ?

Comment: I doubt it has to do with low res images. The majority of my view are basic elements like textviews and edittext. To be more specific, I've added comment in the xml to show where the problem starts. Basically, the last TextView and EditText are off the screen.

Comment: If you want to set layout_weight=1 you should set layout_height to 0dp+. Also in your first snippet what is the layout you are wrapping elements into?